# Register Dll to Specific Path

Tags: c++, windows, registry

While in registering the dll into registry ,it get registered to default path somewhere. Now I want to change this default path and Register my Dll to Specific path in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` hierarchy using *Regsvr32*. I am doing my project in C++. Can anyone please help me out of this ??

Comment: If you DLL is not a COM DLL, then there is no "registration". Are you sure your DLL is based on COM?  Or is it just an ordinary DLL?  In any case, what are you really trying to do?  Show us the code you are using thus far.

Comment: Here is the code for DllRegisterServer .I want to register my Dll in hierarchy of HLM..

Comment: And how to generate the CLSID number for each of the hierarchy under HLM?

Answer (score 0):

`RegSvr32` simply loads the DLL using `LoadLibrary` and uses `GetProcAddress` to get the address of the exported function `DllRegisterServer`. It then calls the `DllRegisterServer` function. So whatever code is in `DllRegisterServer` will be executed. You can add your own registration code in this function.